# Helm can't iterate over range from set-file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to loop over a secret file I'm generating in my ci pipeline.

```
helm template \
  ...
  --set-file secretmap="secretmap.yaml" \
  ...
```

The `secretmap.yaml` is generated and contains the following:

```
SEC_1: 111
SEC_2: 222
...
```

The secret.yaml looks like this:

```
kind: Secret
...
data:
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.secretmap }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $val | b64enc | quote }}
{{- end }}
...
```

And the error I get is:

```
Error: render error in ".../secret.yaml": template: .../secret.yaml:4:31: ... range can't iterate over SEC_1: 111
SEC_1: 222
...
```

The same configuration does work with configmap though,
where I set the configmap from `-f chart/values/common.yaml`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--set-file` sets the contents of the variable to the text contents of the file; it doesn’t try to interpret it at all.  (Somewhat described in [this section of the Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing); note the example there is a JavaScript script being embedded in a ConfigMap.)  That means you need to tell Helm to parse the file.  Helm includes a minimally-documented [`fromYaml`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/engine/funcs.go#L98) function that can do this.

When you iterate through the contents of the value, try explicitly parsing it first:

```
{{- range $key, $val := fromYaml .Values.secretmap }}
...
{{ end }}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `<b64enc>: wrong type for value; expected string; got float64`. I guess it's because one of my secret is a number. This line fails `{{ $key }}: {{ $val | b64enc | quote }}`, how can I fix it?

Comment: Try [converting it](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/conversion.html) `toString`, `$val | toString | b64enc`.